# Code contracts - Not correctly warning about readonly members?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Given this class, I"m not sure why I get the Ensure unproven Result != null warning.

```
public class MyClass {
  private readonly string _value;

  public MyClass(string value) {
    Contract.Requires(value != null);  
    _value = value;
  }

  public string Value {
    get {
      Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
      return _value;
    }
  }
}
```

I can make the warning go away by adding an Invariant that _value != null, but it feels like I shouldn't have to.  Is this just a limitation of the analysis?

**EDIT**:  Adding a bit more to the question, as I think the point of my question is being missed.

```
public class Test {
    private string _value = "";

    public string Value {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
            return _value;
        }
        set {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(value != null);
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The CC analysis seems perfectly happy with this class; a non-null value is assigned in the ctor, and the setter `Requires` non-null values to change `_value` thus `Ensures` is proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor does not promise that  `_value` will be non-null. It sets `_value` to `value`, which is non-null, but that's an implementation detail, not part of the contract. Even if it were part of the contract, it wouldn't be enough, because all pre- and postconditions should remain equally valid when you add another constructor that doesn't make that same promise.

You should add the invariant that `_value != null`. Why does it feel like you shouldn't have to?

*Edit*: as an alternative, you could try adding an invariant that `Value != null` (which would also be useful outside of `MyClass`), and make `Value`'s property getter ensure that `Contract.Result<string>() == _value` (merely to prove the invariant), but I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: It feels like I shouldn't need to add the invariant because with the code as written there actually is no way for _value to be null. _value itself is an implementation detail that outside callers need not concern themselves with, so I don't understand why it would be part of the contract.

Comment: @Andy Making `_value != null` part of the contract doesn't mean it becomes part of the *public* contract. It's a promise that your internal class methods must live up to and can rely on, it's a private contract. As I mentioned in my answer, you could add a second constructor which sets `_value` to null. That's perfectly valid, because you don't have any class invariants that `_value` must be non-null. If that's perfectly valid, then in your current situation, you cannot assume that it is non-null, even though it will always be so as long as you don't add that second constructor.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my question.  Certainly adding a constructor that doesn't ensure `_value` cannot be null means we can't prove that `Ensures` will be met.  But that's not the code in question.  I'm trying to understand why the code I posted thinks `Ensures` cannot be proven, when logically it seems to me it can in fact be proven.  Adding another ctor could break that I understand, but I see no reason `Ensures` should not be satifised with the code as is.

Comment: @Andy That's not how code contracts works. The code in your method should be provable without relying on the code in other methods: it should be provable by relying on other methods' contracts.

Comment: I've added more to my question; maybe this will help you understand better what I'm asking.

Comment: @Andy You still, correctly, get a warning for that. The warning is masked at the "low" warning level, but visible at "high". Note that this warning doesn't appear or disappear depending on a newly added `public void f() { _value = null; }` method.

Comment: Sorry it took a while to get back to this; you're right, I was just missing the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the option was available when the question was asked, but I ran into a similar issue today and found that by turning on the Code Contracts option "Infer Invariants for readonly" the warning went away.

Comment: No, it was not an option when I asked the question m thanks for the info!